# Как сделать горизонтальные блоки одинаковой высоты внутри другого блока?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="1">
  <div class="2"></div>
  <div class="3"></div>
</div>
```

Сделать блоки 2 и 3 одинаковой высоты в процентном соотношении. Они должны отображаться горизонтально, т.е. друг под другом и растягиваться по высоте в зависимости от высоты родителя

Comment: "горизонтально, т.е. друг под другом", может, вертикально?

Answer (score 1):

Если кол-во блоков известно, то можно просто указать значение высоты в процентах 100 / n, где n - количество блоков.

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/VfBQr/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
}

.home
{
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.section
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.333%;
}

.y { background-color: yellow; }
.b { background-color: blue; }
.g { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="section y"></div>
  <div class="section b"></div>
  <div class="section g"></div>
</div>
```